# How can I prevent deadlocks in ApplicationRecoveryCallback()?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, indy

I have registered my application for [ARR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc948909%28v=vs.85%29). Assume that my application has a `IdTCPServer` which reads data from the serial port using [`VSPE`](http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html) and adds it to a `ClientDataSet`. If the main thread freezes, ARR will call my ApplicationRecoveryCallback(). Can I access the `IdTCPServer` in the recovery callback function safely? I want it to stop so that I can save my `ClientDataSet` to the disk before restarting. Can I simply write my function this way?

```
function RecoveryFunction(pvParameter: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
var
  ContinueRecovery: Boolean;
begin
  Result := 0; // happy compiler ;-)
  repeat
    ApplicationRecoveryInProgress(ContinueRecovery);
    if not ContinueRecovery then
      ApplicationRecoveryFinished(False);
  until frmInstrument.CriticalSection.TryEnter;
  frmInstrument.IdTCPServer.Active := False;
  frmInstrument.CDS.SaveToFile(RecoveryFile);
  ApplicationRecoveryFinished(True);
end;
```

Comment: Why don't you just stop the application freezing in the first place?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good question, but this is a last effort to save valuable data _if_ my application is going to die. The data I'm collecting from the serial port is coming from a bunch of medical laboratory instruments with no internal memory, so when I receive a packet, I should guard it with my life, so to speak.

Comment: You guard it by writing it to disk immediately. When you do that, no recovery is required because you've already saved everything available. The ARR documentation advises exactly that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I already save the data immediately after processing it. But in some cases, especially some old "Gamma Counters", the instrument is sending packets far faster that my application can process. There is data in my buffer which still needs to be written and my database server is taking its time responding to my last query. I want to save anything that has yet to be saved in case of a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't write it like that. This function is called when your program has stopped responding. For all you know, it's stopped responding because something else is already stuck waiting for that same critical section.

If you want to be able to access your data even when your program is hung, then you need a lock-free way of detecting when you're allowed to read your data. Use a transaction-log model. Atomically update something that indicates how much of your data is valid. When you enter the recovery function, read that value, and save as much as it says is available. Don't bother reading beyond that point because you can't be certain that it's not corrupt and the reason for your program's crash in the first place.

Comment: Can I access VCL classes in the recovery callback function? My forms, data modules, etc.?

Comment: Of course. Why not? It's all part of your program. Access might not be reliable, though, since your program has already hung or crashed.

Comment: I meant if there could be access violations. For instance, I need to stop all running threads, maybe forcefully, before accessing any data.

Comment: Yes, there could be access violations. There could be anything; you don't know why your program crashed. Don't bother terminating threads unless they're *really* obstructing access to the data you need to rescue. Your application-recovery function should do the *absolute minimum* required. You have to assume that *anything* you do could cause your recovery function to fail, so don't touch anything more than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you move your serial port and CDS logic out of the main thread, you reduce the possibility of your app becoming unresponsive and having ARR kick in at all.  The main thread should be used for UI logic only, business logic that takes awhile to run is better served in worker threads instead.

Comment: My CDS logic is in `IdTCPServerExecute`, and I use `VSPE` to route serial port to TCP, so my main thread is just for UI

Comment: "my main thread is just for UI" - if that were true than your app would not be freezing up.